# Node.js Remove the port from the URL

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, vhosts, express-vhost

I have two **Node.js** apps in my server. They are listing to port `55555`. Here is the directory structure.

```
/home/myuser
  /.htaccess
  /package.json
  /server.js

  /foo.com
    /node_modules
    /public
      /index.html
   /package.json
   /server.js

  /bar.com
    /node_modules
    /public
      /index.html
   /package.json
   /server.js
```

**/home/myuser/server.js content**

```
'use strict';

// Module dependencies.
var express = require('express');
var vhost = require('vhost');

var port = process.env.PORT || 55555;   

function createVirtualHost(domainName, nodeApp) {
    return vhost(domainName, nodeApp);
}

//Create server
var app = express();

var fooApp = require('./foo.com/server.js').app;
var barApp = require('./bar.com/server.js').app;

//Create the virtual hosts
var fooHost = createVirtualHost("www.foo.com", fooApp);
var barHost = createVirtualHost("www.bar.com", barApp);

//Use the virtual hosts
app.use(fooHost);
app.use(barHost);

//Start server
app.listen( port, function() {
    console.log( 'Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', port, app.settings.env );
});
```

**/home/myuser/.htaccess content**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:55555/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:55555/$1 [P,L]
```

When I trying to access `www.foo.com`, I am getting error as:

> Cannot GET /foo.com/index.html.var

When I trying to access `www.bar.com`, I am getting error as:

> Cannot GET /bar.com/index.html.var

But I can access both sites using port like `www.foo.com:55555` and `www.bar.com:55555`

How could I access sites without using port?

Comment: Is port 80 already used on your system?  If you aren't running node, does the system respond with anything just using http://foo.com/ ?

Comment: @SPlatten I can't use port 80 since I am using managed hosting account.

Comment: Then you can't access the URL without using a different port, you have answered your own question.

Comment: @Alex If I removed `.htaccess`, I am getting `You don't have permission to access / on this server.` when I trying to access `www.foo.com`

Comment: htaccess is config file for web servers running Apache. Node runs its own server. They're 2 separate things

Comment: @SPlatten But isn't there a way to redirect users to `foo.com:55555` when they come to `foo.com`?

Comment: @Alex I have followed this [article](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts) and in there, they said use `.htaccess` to integrate node app with web server.

Comment: @Bishan, no because something else is listening on port 80 and when you don't specify a port is the "something" that is going to get the request.

Answer (score -1):

Using Apache as reverse proxy for your app can solve your problem:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Use mod_proxy extension for this.
More information is provided in [this digitalocean article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension).